# file_name.write('something') method in file I/O operation is displaying the word count

Tags: python, file-io

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "w")
fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n")
```

The output on running the above code in my python IDLE is 45.

But according to the documentation , filename.writename() method should return the lines which are specified in the method's arguments

my question is why it is returning the character count, instead of printing the values in the file

Can anybody answer why the output is like that?

Comment: What do you mean "the output is 45"?

Comment: Because ``len("Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n")`` is 45. ``file.write`` returns the number of characters/bytes written.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking what the point is of  ``file.write`` returning the size? Are you asking why the returned size is printed?

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi for the clarification in many sites the output is like below:
     Python is a great language. Yeah its great!!

That's why I was confused

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything…

Comment: @martineau my question was , why the fo.write('something') is returning the count of the words 

As MisterMiyagi told, the exact work of fo.write() , so that's why it clarifies my question

Comment: but according to documentation
The write() method writes any string to an open file.
How it is returning the count - still confused

Comment: You should clarify your question *in your question*. Folks shouldn't have to read every comment in order to determine what it is you want to know.

Comment: Basically [every variation of io.write is documented to "return the number of ... written"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), so I'm a bit confused that you refer to the documentation but are still confused that it behaves as such.

Comment: Okay, so according to the documentation, it says it will write in the file
But you are saying that it will return the character count
that's the confusion, 
The output 45, I tried myself in python IDLE, but in the documentation, it is printing the lines which are specified in the filename.write argument

Comment: The documentations says it will write to the file *and* return the character count. "``io.TextIOBase.write(s)`` Write the string s to the stream and return the number of characters written." "``io.RawIOBase.write(b)`` Write the given bytes-like object, b, to the underlying raw stream, and return the number of bytes written."

Comment: okay, Thanks for the instant answers and clarification.

Comment: "But according to the documentation , filename.writename() method should return the lines which are specified in the method's arguments" no, the documentation doesn't say that anywhere. It clearly documents that `.write` returns the number of bytes written (or "characters" if it is a text stream)